Can I adjust this SELECT query without using a WHERE clause in python using MySQL?
I have the following function is python, which is not working:
    def get_expenses_by_type(self, current_user):
        try:
            cursor = self.main_db.cursor(dictionary=True)
            if self.check_user_level(current_user) == 0:
                query = """
                    SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                    FROM ExpenseTable
                    WHERE UserID = %s
                    GROUP BY Date, Type;
                """
            else:
                query = """
                    SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                    FROM ExpenseTable
                    GROUP BY Date, Type;
                """
            cursor.execute(query, (current_user,))
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return results
        except Exception as error:
            raise error

When I run the code, if the user level is greater than 0, I get the following error raised:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Could anyone help please?

You can move the query parameters into another variable. Then you can make this an empty tuple when you don't have a WHERE clause.
def get_expenses_by_type(self, current_user):
    try:
        cursor = self.main_db.cursor(dictionary=True)
        if self.check_user_level(current_user) == 0:
            query = """
                SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                FROM ExpenseTable
                WHERE UserID = %s
                GROUP BY Date, Type;
            """
            params = (current_user,)
        else:
            query = """
                SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                FROM ExpenseTable
                GROUP BY Date, Type;
            """
            params = ()
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return results
    except Exception as error:
        raise error


I realised the solution was within how I was executing the query. In either scenario, I was executing the query and using the parameter of the current user: cursor.execute(query, (current_user,)). The solution was to have two execute statements, one in each selection:
def get_expenses_by_type(self, current_user):
    try:
        cursor = self.main_db.cursor(dictionary=True)
        if self.check_user_level(current_user) == 0:
            query = """
                SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                FROM ExpenseTable
                WHERE UserID = %s
                GROUP BY Date, Type;
            """
            cursor.execute(query, (current_user,))
        else:
            query = """
                SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                FROM ExpenseTable
                GROUP BY Date, Type;
            """
            cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        # Convert the query results into a dictionary
        return results
    except Exception as error:
        raise error

This worked as intended.

def get_expenses_by_type(self, current_user):
    try:
        cursor = self.main_db.cursor(dictionary=True)
        query = """
                SELECT Date, Type, SUM(Price * Quantity) AS TotalAmount
                FROM ExpenseTable
                WHERE (UserID = %s) OR (%s = 0)
                GROUP BY Date, Type;
                """
        cursor.execute(query, (current_user, self.check_user_level(current_user),))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        # Convert the query results into a dictionary
        return results
    except Exception as error:
        raise error

PS. python syntax may be incorrect - I don't know it..
